# Write to one output file from a few parallel LSF bsub jobs, avoiding writing at the same time

Tags: unix, lsf

I have developed a code that composed of two files:
An 'envelop bash file', which does a few things and writes to a log-file, and then at some point runs into a for loop in which within it it executes one job at a time using bsub.
And 'an internal bash file', which gets as input the name of the log-file (in addition to other input values that necessary for its execution), and executes process X (using the input values it received from the 'envelop file'. 
Once process X is finished, the 'internal script' writes to the log-file that process X (with its specific serial number) has been completed.

Since the for-loop of the envelop file loops 10 times, there are at least 10 parallel processes that being executed and run in parallel, and they all being executed with bsub given the SAME log-file name. The idea is that they would all report to the same log-file once they completed their execution of Process X.

The general procedure works well, and in each case process X is being executed, and the log-file accumulates as required all the notifications regarding the completion of process X. However, in some incidences we see that the writing to the log-file get disturbed and output lines of two parallel runs are running into each other.
I would like to lock the log-file in such manner that would allow it to receive text only from one parallel run at a time. The idea is to avoid cases where the text becomes mixed due to two processes that write by chance to the log-file exactly at the same time.

Here is the part of my envelop file which call to the bsub (I reduced the content to the minimum necessary):

```
for ((i=1;i<=$batchesnumber; i++));
do
   bsub -J $SerialName -q normal "bash FetchFasta.bash $genome_fa ${SerialFileName}".bed" $logfile"
done
```

Here is the part of my internal file that echo to the log-file:

```
( 
echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
echo "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
echo -n "Completed running "; bedtools -version
echo "bedtools getfasta -s -fi $genome_fasta -bed $mySerialFile -fo ${mySerialFile%.*}".fa" "
echo "Run's completion time is: $timedate"
echo -e "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n"
) >> $logfile
```

I would appreciate any useful solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of ways I can think of going about this:

1. Have each job write its output to a different file (use `$LSB_JOBID` inside each job to name the file). Then use another "cleanup" job to concatenate all of the ouptut into a single file.  You can use job dependencies (`bsub -w`) to make sure the cleanup job runs after all the other jobs are done.
2. Implement a lock inside your "internal" job to make sure only one of them writes to a file at a time.  This is a lot simpler than it might sound, one way to do it is to have each job try to create the same directory with `mkdir` before writing to the file and then delete the directory after its done.  If they fail to create the directory it's because another one of the jobs got to it first and is currently writing to the file.

Here's a snippet illustrating #2 in bash:

```
# Try to get the lock every second
while ! mkdir lock &> /dev/null ; do
     sleep 1
done

# Got the lock, write to the logfile
echo blahblahblah >> $logfile

# Release the lock
rmdir lock
```

I should mention an important caveat here though: if one of your jobs dies while it's "holding the lock" (say someone sends it a kill signal at the wrong time) then it'll never remove the directory and all the other jobs won't be able to create it, so they'll just keep sleeping forever.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Squirrel ! 
the first solution I've actually end up using. But I really like the idea behind your second solution, which is basically the neat solution i was looking for to start with. I was told to use the filelock function but our bsub LSF dosen't support it.  Can you please explain what stands exactly behind the part:  while ! mkdir lock &> /dev/null  (i just want to see if i fully grasped it). Thanks!

Comment: Sure, the basic idea is that the loop condition runs `mkdir lock` and tests the output.  If it succeeded, it means it successfully created the directory and therefore "owns the lock", if it failed then `mkdir lock` returns non-zero and therefore `! mkdir lock` is true and we enter the loop, which in turn causes the logic to sleep for one second and try again.  The `&> /dev null` part just suppresses any output.  The reason we use `mkdir` instead of (say) checking for a file and using `touch` to create a lock is that it allows us to check for the directory and create it in a single step.